# What is assigned to `variable`, in `with expression as variable`?

Tags: python, python-3.x

From Learning Python:

> The basic format of the with statement looks like this, with an
>   optional part in square brackets here:
>
> ```
> with expression [as variable]:
>     with-block
> ```
>
> The `expression` here is assumed to return an object that supports the
>   context management protocol (more on this protocol in a moment).
>   **This object may also return a value that will be assigned to the name `variable` if the optional as clause is present.**
>
> Note that **the `variable` is not necessarily assigned the result of
>   the `expression`**; the result of the `expression` is the object that
>   supports the context protocol, and **the `variable` may be assigned
>   something else intended to be used inside the statement.**

`expression` is evaluated to a context manager object.

What is assigned to `variable`? The quote only says that it is not a context manager object.

Does the assignment to `variable` call  some method of a context manager class to produce the actual value assigned to `variable`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whatever is returned from `__enter__`. From the [documentation on the `__enter__` method of context managers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#context-manager-types):

> `contextmanager.__enter__()`
>
> Enter the runtime context and return either this object or another object related to the runtime context. *The value returned by this method is bound to the identifier in the `as` clause of `with` statements using this context manager.*

<sub>(Emphasis mine)</sub>

The result of calling `__enter__` could very well be a context manager, nothing in the specification forbids this. It could of course be another object related to the runtime context, as the docs state.

Objects that return themselves from `__enter__` can be used again and again as context managers. [`file` objects](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object), for example:

```
with open('test_file') as f1:   # file.__enter__ returns self
    with f1 as f2:                # use it again, get __self__ back
        print("Super context managing")
        with f2 as f3, f1 as f4:   # getting weird.
            print("This can go on since f1.__enter__ returns f1")
        print("f1.__exit__ has been called here, though :)")
        print("f1 closed: {}".format(f1.closed))
```

Not that the previous made much sense but just to make the point clear.

Answer (score 9):

Your object can function as a context manager if it [provides both `__enter__` and `__exit__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers). The object returned by `__enter__` is bound to the object you specify in the `as` part of the `with` statement:

```
In [1]: class Foo:
   ...:     def __enter__(self):
   ...:         return 'hello'
   ...:     def __exit__(self, *args):
   ...:         pass
   ...:

In [2]: with Foo() as a:
   ...:     print(a)
   ...:
hello
```